# Can I have a sticky footer and also line up my main background image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I've built a portfolio site for a friend of mine - that I'm having a small issue with. I'm not personally sure if it's solvable, but let's see!

She would like to have a sticky footer on the homepage, but also have the main image/gif fully in view above it. So I've given the main image a max width, and centred it.

The problem now is that the background of the image is a grid/checkbox style pattern (not css grid, a visual grid). So I've put that behind the image, which means it won't really ever line up with the main image.

Here's the link, I'm sure it'll make much more sense by seeing it! https://magpie.work/

Is there any way around this?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: This will inevitably happen with those types of backgrounds, your best bet is for the gif to be transparent.

Comment: It also uses a different color mode so it doesn't look the same as your background.

Comment: Also, you should check more on optimizing images, because the image switching thing in your sections is waaay too heavy.

Comment: Hey, ahh yes the transparent background for the gif makes loads of sense, not sure why I did't think of that!

Fully agreed on the image optimisation, but unfortunately she wouldn't let me. She's a graphic designer, and said the quality of the images comes above everything else, so they couldn't be touched.